# Add tag img-responsive to <img>

Tags: php

I need to write a script that will add an img-responsive class to HTML images.

So in the HTML code:
a) It will search if there are any `<img>` tags with the class option, if so, it will add it to the current img-responsive class
b)If the image does not have a class, we only add a class with img-responsive.

Does anyone know how to do this?

My current code (it's not working):

```
function addImgResponsiveClass($matches) {
            if (!empty($matches[2])) {
                $replacement = $matches[1] . 'class="' . $matches[2] . ' img-responsive"' . $matches[3];
            } else {
                $replacement = $matches[1] . 'class="img-responsive"' . $matches[2] . $matches[3];
            }
            return $replacement;
        }
        
        $txtD = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(<img\s+)(class="([^"]*)"\s*)?(.*?>)/i',
            'addImgResponsiveClass',
            dynamicCaption($dataArray[0]['content_pl'])
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regex at all. That is not the right tool for manipulating and parsing HTML.

***Note**: LoadHTML() does only work if there is a root element. In this case there is none, so I create `html` as a wrapper and remove it on output. In case you have a full HTML file, you can omit that steps.*

```
$html = <<<'_HTML_'
<img alt="no class">
<img class="" alt="empty class">
<img class="lazyload" alt="lazyload">
_HTML_;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html>' . $html . '</html>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
    $class = $image->getAttribute('class') ?? '';
    $image->setAttribute('class', ltrim($class . ' img-responsive'));
}

echo str_replace(['<html>', '</html>'], '', $dom->saveHTML());
```

```
<img alt="no class" class="img-responsive">
<img class="img-responsive" alt="empty class">
<img class="lazyload img-responsive" alt="lazyload">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with your `regex` and the `class` attribute, hope the following helps:

```
function addImgResponsiveClass($matches) {
    if (!empty($matches[2])) {
        $replacement = $matches[1] . 'class="' . trim($matches[2]) . ' img-responsive"' . $matches[4];
    } else {
        $replacement = $matches[1] . 'class="img-responsive" ' . $matches[4];
    }
    return $replacement;
}

$txtD = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<img\s+)(class="([^"]*)"\s*)?(.*?>)/i',
    'addImgResponsiveClass',
    dynamicCaption($dataArray[0]['content_pl'])
);
```